# Arduino serial controlled tone generator only working with single digit ints?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, speaker

I'm writing a small program for my arduino which allows me to send two int values over serial to be interpreted. The first is a frequency Hz value and the second is a a length milsec value.

The code works, and plays the correct tone for the correct amount of millis, but only for single digit integers. If a double or more digit integer is sent then the arduino loops through the code several times and plays the wrong tone.

Here is my code:

```
const byte LED = 13; /* LED Pin */
const byte SPK = 12; /* Speaker Pin */
const int BAUD_RATE = 19200; /* Baud Rate of Input */

void setup(){
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SPK, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  Serial.setTimeout(0);
  tone(SPK, 1000);
  delay(200);
  noTone(SPK);
  Serial.println("System ready for data");
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("tone");
  while(Serial.available() == false){
    delay(0);
  }
  int toneToPlay = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println("delay");
  while(Serial.available() == false){
    delay(0);
  }
  int delayValue = Serial.parseInt();

  tone(SPK, toneToPlay);
  delay(delayValue);
  noTone(SPK);
}
```

Expected result is the ability to enter any tone and delay and the arduino plays it then asks for another tone and delay.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my new code. It does what I want, the only issue is there is a pause after I type the tone value before it asks for the delay value, and a pause after the delay value before it plays the tone. I can't have this delay as data will eventually be sent by a piece of software to the arduino. How can I fix this delay? New code:

```
const byte LED = 13; /* LED Pin */
const byte SPK = 12; /* Speaker Pin */
const int BAUD_RATE = 19200; /* Baud Rate of Input */

void setup(){
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SPK, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  tone(SPK, 1000);
  delay(200);
  noTone(SPK);
  Serial.println("System ready for data");
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("tone");
  while(Serial.available() == false){
    delay(0);
  }
  int toneToPlay = Serial.readString().toInt();
  Serial.println("delay");
  while(Serial.available() == false){
    delay(0);
  }
  int delayValue = Serial.readString().toInt();

  tone(SPK, toneToPlay);
  delay(delayValue);
  noTone(SPK);
}
```

Comment: 1) What do you mean by `delay(0)`? 2) Have you tried typing faster?

Comment: Try non-blocking read to a buffer instead. Build a string to convert to an integer. And check how parseInt() works. There is a timeout! This might not be sufficient.

Comment: @EdgarBonet the delay(0) is a time filler which make the arduino do something while it waits for serial data. I can't type fast enough, I get five requests within a fraction of a second.

Comment: @MikaelPatel Non-blocking read buffer?? Whats that?

Comment: @MikaelPatel I know there is a timeout. I tried to turn off the timeout at the start of the code with Serial.setTimeout(0). I'll try the string thing now.

Comment: 1) This “filler” serves no useful purpose. You can just remove it, your code will only be cleaner. 2) If you really did `setTimeout(0)`, then of course you cannot type fast enough! You have just asked `Serial` to wait no more than 0 milliseconds for you to type the digits.

Comment: The Arduino readString, parseInt() etc functions are inherently flawed in the way they work. Don't use them if you value your sanity. Read this for how to do it properly: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: Hint: How does it know when you've fished typing your number and there are no more digits to follow?

Comment: @Majenko I'll try this later